# What is Chinese for "Arts Festival"?

Tags: word-requests

I am referring to events such as the [Edinburgh Festival](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edinburgh_Festival).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha.. found it by looking up the [Chinese Edinburgh Festival site](http://www.eif.co.uk/simplified-chinese). Guess I should have searched around more before asking here. Answer is:

> 艺术节

节 means festival in most situations where the English word would be used, so Edinburgh Festival is 爱丁堡节, film festival is 电影节。

Comment: Where did you find it? Could you expand the answer a little so it gets some additional quality? :)

Comment: *asked 1 hour ago - answered 1 hour ago*, yes I guess so :D

Comment: @Petruza Was that for me? If yes, I didn't understand then. :P

Comment: No, if it was, I would've @Alenanno it, it was for the poster.

Comment: sure i'll expand

Comment: I think the question needs more clarification in terms of its context. If the context is referring to the festival as an assembly, (文化)艺术大會 might be more appropriate. However, if is the event segment (as in the occasion) then is 节 might be more appropriate.

Comment: @Krazer. When it is used in the context of a place name + Festival (As in Edinburgh Festival) it refers to the whole occasion.